# Separate build and test jobs for AppVeyor

Tags: github, automated-tests, appveyor

I am rather new to the integration service AppVeyor and I want to know, whether and how it is possible to setup the following jobs for a connected GitHub-Project:

```
job1
    build master-branch
    test master-branch
job2
    build dev-branch without testing
job3
    build dev-branch
    test dev-branch
```

I know, that the web-interface allows to turn on and off build tests, but I have not found out yet how to configure separate jobs and assign them the specific `build`- and `test`-tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Conditional build configuration](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/#conditional-build-configuration). Configuration sample in that document is about different deployment options for different branch, but you can configure different test options as well.

Comment: I got some parsing errors according to the webinterface, but nevermind ... I separated the whole thing into two AppVeyor projects - one for testing and one for building

Comment: https://ci.appveyor.com/tools/validate-yaml is useful tool if you decide to come back to single YAML